# Writing to .dat file results in random Chinese characters being written

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I have this program:

```
using namespace std;

class Motherboards
{
    char Board_Manufacturer_Name[50];
    char Socket_Type[50];
    char Chipset_Type[50];
    char Board_Name[50];
    char Feature1[500];
    char Feature2[500];
    char Feature3[500];
    float Price;

    public:
    void getdata();
    void displaydata();
};
void Motherboards::getdata()
{
    cout << " Enter Manufacturer Name :\n";
    cin.getline(Board_Manufacturer_Name, 50);
    cout << "\n Enter the Socket type :\n";
    cin.getline(Socket_Type, 50);
    cout << "\n Enter the Chipset Type :\n";
    cin.getline(Chipset_Type, 50);
    cout << "\n Enter the Board Name :\n";
    cin.getline(Board_Name, 50);
    cout << "\n Enter 3 main features for this Board :\n";
    cout << "\n1.) ";
    cin.getline(Feature1, 500);
    cout << "\n2.) ";
    cin.getline(Feature2, 500);
    cout << "\n3.) ";
    cin.getline(Feature3, 500);
    cout << "Price :\n";
    cin >> Price;
    cout << "\n";
}
void Motherboards::displaydata()
{
    cout << " Manufacturer : " << Board_Manufacturer_Name << endl;
    cout << " Socket : " << Socket_Type << endl;
    cout << " Chipset : " << Chipset_Type << endl;
    cout << " Board Name : " << Board_Name << endl;
    cout << " Features :\n" << "1.) " << Feature1 << endl
        << "2.) " << Feature2 << endl
        << "3.) " << Feature3 << endl;
    cout << " Price :\n" << Price;
    cout << "\n";
} 

int main()
{
    int x;
    system("cls");
    Motherboards M;
    fstream Infile;
    Infile.open("MotherboardList.dat", ios::in | ios::out | ios::app);
    if (!Infile)
    {
        cerr << "Error :";
    }
    cout << "Enter the details of the motherboard that you want to add :\n";
    M.getdata();
    Infile.write((char*)&M, sizeof(M));
    cout << "Do you wanna confirm ?";
    M.displaydata();
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Written :\n";
    Infile.read((char*)&M, sizeof(M));
    M.displaydata();
    Infile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

I get this output:

[image: output]

Why is my data written in some random language (maybe Chinese?), and what do I have to change to actually write the data properly?

I wanted the text file to be in English. Also, shouldn't there be a line break after each data I entered?

Comment: Did you try to step through your code, with a debugger?

Comment: Yeah tried both with and without it

Comment: But, did you try to **step through** your code, step-by-step? By watching the values of the variables? And looking for when the code does something, that deviates from your expectations?

Comment: Yeah they were all working individually

Comment: What _they_? Step through and investigate the code, that is misbehaving. That`s debugging - and, while developing, you will need to do it quite a lot, so earlier you learn - the better off you are in the long run.

Comment: Oh sorry by 'they' i meant when i individually checked if the  values were picked up correctly and it did . Up until that point it was ok but when i write that to the file that`s when it`s in Chinese.
In the code before i do 'cin >> x;' i used 'M.Getdata' so yes that part is working fine

Comment: There was a PDB error which i fixed and there are no errors now but it still does the same thing. i tried changing .dat to .txt to see if there were any changes if it was a text file but it was same all over again

Comment: why you are not using std::string ?

Answer (score 0):

The file you create is not a valid text file, but a binary file.
you are writing internals of a c++ struct to the file in its binary representation.

if you want the file to be human readable, serialize your struct to string before writing to file, use JSON or XML.

And de-serialize after reading back if you want the c program to understand it.